# Mysql2: close client connection

Tags: ruby, database, connection, client, mysql2

I am using `Mysql2` to query a database on `ruby`. I initialize the connection by:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :database => 'mydb', :username => "root")
```

Once the query is done successfully, how can I close the client connection? If I do not close it, I soon reach the maximum number of possible open connections.

#### Solution

Thanks to @joonty:

`client.close`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Can you post a Gist with your solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `client.close`. [From the docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/Mysql2/Client#close-instance_method):

> Mysql2::Client#close
>
> Immediately disconnect from the server, normally the garbage collector will disconnect automatically when a connection is no longer needed. Explicitly closing this will free up server resources sooner than waiting for the garbage collector.

Have you got multiple long-running processes that only use the mysql connection for a short time? That should be the only case where this is an issue. If your processes are ending then the connection will be closed as part of garbage collection, so your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't solve my problem. I need the `MySql2::Client` in an API to make simple queries on a DB. So, I don't think that the problem involves multiple long-running processes. Basically, whenever a `get` request is done, a new `MySql2::Client` is open and the query is performed. I now added the `cient.close` after each request, but I still have the same problem: too many connections open.

Comment: Me too, I have the same problem. Any idea on how this can be resolved?