# Disconnecting from mysql database in rufus scheduler doesnt work (dashing.io)

Tags: mysql, dashing, rufus-scheduler, database-connection

I am using dashing.io and want to grab some data from a mysql database using rufus scheduler to push them.

I have this code for testing the connection closing in one .rb job file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'
SCHEDULER.every '12h', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  begin
    db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "rainer-zufall", :port => 2971, :database => "test" )
    open_connections = db.query("show status like 'Connections';")
    open_connections.each do |row|
      puts "connections: #{row}"
    end
  rescue

  ensure
    db.close
  end
end
```

The database connection do not close. The connection counter still increases and soon there will be an error stating max_connections reached from the mysql-server.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Cross referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180822/mysql2-close-client-connection

Comment: Please indicate what version of the mysql2 gem you are using. Eventually try with the latest one (0.4.5).

Comment: Does the code at https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/f66ebd02408001f3662338869dfc00f1 show the same problem?

Comment: @jmettraux using mysql2 version 0.4.5.

Comment: Which Ruby version? Which Operating System? Which Dashing version? Which MySQL version? Which Fridolin password?

Comment: @jmettraux: Thank You.  Unfortunately your gist example does not close the db conneciton properly;
ruby 2.2.1p85; CentOS7,  dashing 1.3.7, MySQL  5.7.16

Comment: So the problem is not with rufus-scheduler. You should look at mysql2 issues and eventually report there. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2